# How can I reflect chapter title case in table of content too?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, uppercase

Using below code to make chapters uppercased,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{{CHAPTER}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\large \bfseries \centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\MakeUppercase}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{-10pt}{-20pt}{25pt}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Background}
Background

\subsection{Story 1}
\subsection{Story 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But found table of content chapter titles are not yet uppercased. How can I reflect chapter title case in table of content too?

Comment: I answered something similar a few days ago: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531105/getting-only-capital-letters-in-the-table-of-contents/531119#531119. Hope it works as you want!

Comment: Did you see my updated answer to your previous question?

Comment: Yes it worked Bernard

Comment: The `tocloft` package should have let you do this but it doesn't as yet. Hopefully a new version will be available soon whereby you can use `tocloft` and say`\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries\MakeUppercase}` and get uppercase titles in the ToC.